# Sort array top level by next level value - Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to sort the films in this array by the popularity value. How can I do this?

```
[
  { 
    "id"=>1,  
    "popularity"=>7.77030797174916, 
    "title"=>"Another film",
  }, 
  { 
    "id"=>2,  
    "popularity"=>2.7703074916, 
    "title"=>"A film",
  },
  { 
    "id"=>3,  
    "popularity"=>9.77030797174916, 
    "title"=>"A third film",
  }
]
```

Comment: use `sort_by` and then write a block which pulls out popularity

Answer (score 3):

`my_array.sort_by { |e| e['popularity'] }`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously We should use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) here.

```
a = [
  { 
    "id"=>1,  
    "popularity"=>7.77030797174916, 
    "title"=>"Another film",
  }, 
  { 
    "id"=>2,  
    "popularity"=>2.7703074916, 
    "title"=>"A film",
  },
  { 
    "id"=>3,  
    "popularity"=>9.77030797174916, 
    "title"=>"A third film",
  }
]
a.sort_by{|h| h["popularity"]}
# => [{"id"=>2, "popularity"=>2.7703074916, "title"=>"A film"},
#     {"id"=>1, "popularity"=>7.77030797174916, "title"=>"Another film"},
#     {"id"=>3, "popularity"=>9.77030797174916, "title"=>"A third film"}]
```

Or I could also use `Enumerable#sort` :

```
a = [
  { 
    "id"=>1,  
    "popularity"=>7.77030797174916, 
    "title"=>"Another film",
  }, 
  { 
    "id"=>2,  
    "popularity"=>2.7703074916, 
    "title"=>"A film",
  },
  { 
    "id"=>3,  
    "popularity"=>9.77030797174916, 
    "title"=>"A third film",
  }
]
a.sort{|h1,h2| h1["popularity"] <=> h2["popularity"]}
# => [{"id"=>2, "popularity"=>2.7703074916, "title"=>"A film"},
#     {"id"=>1, "popularity"=>7.77030797174916, "title"=>"Another film"},
#     {"id"=>3, "popularity"=>9.77030797174916, "title"=>"A third film"}]
```

**BENCHMARK**

```
require 'benchmark'

a = [
  { 
    "id"=>1,  
    "popularity"=>7.77030797174916, 
    "title"=>"Another film",
  }, 
  { 
    "id"=>2,  
    "popularity"=>2.7703074916, 
    "title"=>"A film",
  },
  { 
    "id"=>3,  
    "popularity"=>9.77030797174916, 
    "title"=>"A third film",
  }
]

Benchmark.bm(100) do |b|
  b.report("Sort")    { a.sort{|h1,h2| h1["popularity"] <=> h2["popularity"]} }
  b.report("Sort by") { a.sort_by{|h| h["popularity"]} }
end

                 user     system      total        real
Sort         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000041)
Sort by      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000019)
```